# Cannot margin <legend> on a top of a fieldset

Tags: html, css

I got a fieldset working - here is the code:

```
                            <fieldset>
                            <legend>Signed In Users (220)</legend>
                            <div>
                                <div class="new_user"><span>Welcome to the new user:&nbsp;<strong>Name_name</strong></span></div>
                                <div class="logusers">Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin</div>
                                <div class="ranks">
                                    Admins | Admins | Admins | Admins | Admins | Admins | Admins | Admins | Admins | Admins | Admins | Admins 
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
```

in css:

```
fieldset {
display: table-cell;
width: 100;
border: 1px solid gray !important;
border-radius: 5px;
border-top-right-radius: 0 !important;
background-color: #d3e1e5 }
legend {
    width: inherit !important;
    padding: 0 5px !important;
    background-color: #d3e1e5;
    border-style: none none !important;
    text-align: right !important;
    border-left: 1px solid gray !important;
    border-right: 1px solid gray !important;
    border-top: 1px solid gray !important;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    margin-right: -1px !important;
    margin-top: -9px !important;
}
```

I got it working in firefox and it this is how it looks and how I want it to look in all browsers - [image: Firefox]
And this is how it looks in different browsers, eg. Chrome.
[image: Chrome]

I really appreciate any help :)
Thank you all so much!

- THANK YOU ALL SO MUCH. I knew I should of used position: absolute. I appreciate the help so much :>

Comment: [Create new fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vtuu9ead/ - doesn't look exactly how I want.

Comment: This is inadequate use of `fieldset`; it should be used to group *controls* and associated labels. If you are using it just for styling, it would probably be easiest to use just `div` elements and style them as desired. Using `fieldset` means that you get some browser oddities and quirks related to this element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this css. I have removed the use of !important because it is not necessary and could cause you problems if you try to overwrite any of the css at a later point in your .css file.

I have also grouped the common styles together and used 'position:absolute;' like the other answers have suggested.

```
fieldset, legend{
    border: 1px solid gray;
    background-color: #d3e1e5;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 0px;
}
fieldset {
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    margin-top: 20px; /*put a margin above the fieldset to leave space for the legend*/
    position:relative; 
}
legend {
    padding: 0 5px;
    text-align: right;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
    position:absolute; /*absolutely position the legend*/
    right:-1px; /*position the legend 1px to the right so that it overlaps the border*/
    top:-19px; /*position the legend 1px down from the top that it overlaps the border*/
}
```

Comment: I added !important because I am using bootstrap and must overwrite it, else it wont work.

Comment: OK! I Choose this answer. its the cleanest one. - I made some tweaks because the numbers are not exactly right but, Thank you. it all works. - **Thank you all GUYS. You all helped me! :)**

Answer (score 0):

I update your CSS in fiddler see if it's ok

```css
fieldset {
 display: table-cell;
 width: 100;
 border: 1px solid #808080 !important;
 border-radius: 5px;
 border-top-right-radius: 0 !important;
 background-color: #D3E1E5;
 position: relative;
 margin-top:25px;
} 
legend {
 width: inherit !important;
 padding: 0 5px !important;
 background-color: #D3E1E5;
 border-style: none none !important;
 text-align: right !important;
 border-left: 1px solid #808080 !important;
 border-right: 1px solid #808080 !important;
 border-top: 1px solid #808080 !important;
 border-top-left-radius: 5px;
 border-top-right-radius: 5px;
 margin-right: 25px !important;
 margin-top: -25px !important;
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bt3p8x75/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:  few workarounds in CSS will solve your problem

i will Suggest do not use negative values in CSS, it will definitely result in cross browser issues, use it only if you does not have options.

```css
   

 fieldset {
 display: table-cell;
 width: 100;
 border: 1px solid gray !important;
 border-radius: 5px;
 margin-top: 15px !important;
 border-top-right-radius: 0 !important;
 background-color: #d3e1e5 
}

legend {
    width: inherit !important;
    padding: 0 5px !important;
    background-color: #d3e1e5;
    border-style: none none !important;
    text-align: right !important;
    border: 1px solid gray !important;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    margin-right: -1px !important;
    margin-top: 2px !important;
    position:fixed;
    right:7px;
    top:0px;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
 <div>
  <legend>Signed In Users (220)</legend>                              
  <div class="new_user">
   <span>Welcome to the new user:&nbsp;
    <strong>Name_name</strong>
   </span>
  </div>
  <div class="logusers">
   Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin
  </div>
  <div class="ranks">
   Admins | Admins | Admins | Admins | Admins | Admins | Admins | Admins | Admins | Admins | Admins | Admins 
  </div>
 </div>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should then use some other HTML attribute for rendering the text of the legend visually, span or div... And use the legend with sr-only CSS class for semantics and screen-readers. That's how I solved this issue :)